Changing no. decimal points displayed for quantile values on boxplot [ggboxplot() + stat_summary(.."%1.1f"..)]
I am using R (v4.4.2).
CONTEXT:
I have a data frame, called "soil moisture", with relevant variables of Substrate (categorical values, "Dung" and "Sand") and SM (continuous soil moisture values). I am using basic t.tests to compare the soil moisture values between pots of each substrate, measured twice a week for several months.



Pot
Date
Substrate
SM




1
2023-11-03
Sand
73.00


2
2023-11-03
Dung
206.00


1
2023-11-04
Sand
69.00


2
2023-11-04
Dung
178.00



prior to testing, I am trying to create a boxplot, to compare the soil moisture measurements between substrates graphically:
Code used:
#a) filtering out my missing values, so as not to have an NA column come up on the boxplot
filtered <- soil_moisture_2 %>% filter(!is.na(SM))

#b) plotting
ggboxplot(filtered, x = "Substrate", y = "SM", 
          color = "Substrate", palette = c("#77811e", "darkorange2"), 
          width = 0.5,
          order = c("Dung", "Sand"),
          ylab = "Soil Moisture (ppm?)", xlab = "Substrate", add = "jitter", shape = "Substrate") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 0.32, by = 0.02),limits = c(0, 0.32))+
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun.y=quantile, 
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y.., digits =.3), color=Substrate), 
               position=position_nudge(x=0.33), size=3.5)

The output looks like this:
enter image description here
MY QUESTION:
I would like to change the number of decimal points to 3, since some quantile values otherwise come up as the same (e.g. 0.2 in dung values)...
C) Here are the actual quantile values for my data:
soil_moisture %>% group_by(Substrate) %>% get_summary_stats(SM, type = "quantile")




Substrate
variable
n
0%
25%
50%
75%
100%




1 Sand
SM
375
0.000^
0.045
0.060
0.075
0.179


2 Dung
SM
269
0.016
0.130
0.161
0.184
0.301



0.000^ -> This one is 0.000100
It seems that "%1.1f" in stat_summary defines the number of decimal points.
I have played around a lot to try and change the decimals.
The best I can do is get the correct quantiles but with several zeros afterwards (e.g. 0.045000)... by changing this to "%f"
Can anyone help me to get the quantile values to display as in the output in C) above
Perhaps I could input the values manually? I have tried looking but can't find ways to do this.
